# Can "anyways" be used at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-starts

For example, is it acceptable to say “Anyways, I love Stack Exchange" or should "anyway" always be used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Paul Brians’ book named "[Common Errors in English Usage](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/errors.html)":

> “**Anyways**” at the beginning of a
>   sentence usually indicates that the
>   speaker has resumed a narrative
>   thread: “Anyways, I told Matilda that
>   guy was a lazy bum before she ever
>   married him.” It also occurs at the
>   end of phrases and sentences, meaning
>   “in any case“: “He wasn’t all that
>   good-looking anyways.” A slightly less
>   rustic quality can be imparted to
>   these sentences by substituting the
>   more formal **anyway**. Neither expression
>   is a good idea in formal written
>   English. The two-word phrase “any way”
>   has many legitimate uses, however: “Is
>   there any way to prevent the impending
>   disaster?”

So you may prefer using "anyways" colloquially but "anyway" is a more formal way.

Comment: Actually, that quote suggests to me that in formal English *neither* should be used.

Comment: You're right. I meant that "anyway" is better than "anyways" as it is referred to as more formal.

Comment: +1 for "A slightly less rustic quality…" :-)

Comment: RE: Neither expression is a good idea in formal written English While not grammatically incorrect, using "Anyway", or "Anyways" in the beginning of a sentence, either written or verbal, is usually not the most concise way to write and does not add anything to the point. It is more of a filler word, such as "Because of the fact that" and is unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

Any has to be followed by a singular noun. Anyways is grammatically inaccurate. Of course, dismissing a commonly used construct can be considered pedantry.

Comment: I have to doubt your claim that “any” has to be followed by a singular noun.  Do you think that the sentence “Do you have any questions?” is grammatically inaccurate?