# Anyway v.s. Anyways

Tags: american-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “Anyways” be used at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/884/can-anyways-be-used-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)
>   [How did 'anyway' become 'anyways,' anyway?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10847/how-did-anyway-become-anyways-anyway)

Is **Anyways** correct or **Anyway** correct?

From chat of EL&U:

*Anyways* is slangy, [is dialect used by Americans mostly.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5442107#5442107).

But Anyways is [informal AND incorrect both.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5442169#5442169)

For example: Sorry for missing our trip. ANYWAY/ANYWAYS, let's make another one some time next month.

So, which one is correct? **Anyways** or **Anyway.**

**Updated:**

[Possible Duplicate question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/884/can-anyways-be-used-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)